# Add discount price on product page

Tags: commerce

I use drupal commerce 2
I want to add some discount on my products, so I had enabled the promotion module and created a promotion whithout coupon.
First of all is that the good way to create a discount on a product ?

Now I want to display the basic price and the discount one one the product page but I can't find a way to get this discount whithout having an order.
What am I missing ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is still in development and will be included by the full 2.0 release. Follow progress and / or contribute to the effort here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2805549